Why do children of tailwind grid divs inherit their siblings' classes, such as padding and margin?
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-2">
  <div class="children-1 col-span-1 p-4 border rounded-md flex justify-center items-center bg-red-600 text-white">Hello</div>
  <div class="children-2 col-span-1 p-0 border rounded-md flex justify-center items-center">world</div>
  <div class="children-3 col-span-1 p-0 border rounded-md flex justify-center items-center">again</div>
</div>

In this provided code, why do children-2 and children-3 inherit the 'p-4' class from children-1 but not the 'bg-red-600' and 'text-white' classes from children-1? What I actually want is different padding for these three siblings.

But when I update the children-2 class from 'col-span-1' to 'col-span-2', only children-2 inherits the 'p-4' class from children-1, but children-3 does not. Why?

It's not inheriting the p-4 of the first item per se. You can see that by making the second element p-8 for example. Note all the elements would stretch to fill the height of the tallest element in that row.
Now when you change the second element's col-span to 2, it takes 2 columns of your 3 column grid, thus making the third element go down to the next row. Since the third element is the tallest of its row, it retains it's height.
That's how grid works.
Now if you want to see the elements have exactly the padding you set, you can add a items-center to your parent container. That'll vertically align your elements to the center. You may as well try items-start or items-end to see how it changes.
